# Convert path queries to url variables with .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, http, url, redirect, url-rewriting

I want to convert an entity query like 'http://www.mysite.com/users' to 'http://www.mysite.com/entities.php?entityName=users'.

How to make such a rewrite rule? Or what should I put into my .htaccess?

Would be great to preserve original url variables, like convert 'http://www.mysite.com/users?fields=ID,UUID' to 'http://www.mysite.com/entities.php?entityName=users&fields=ID,UUID'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to rewrite *(and not to redirect)* */**$users*** to */entities.php?entityName=**$users*** while preserving the original query string, like rewrite */**$users**?fields=ID,UUID* to */entities.php?entityName=**$users**&fields=ID,UUID* then you could try this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ /entities.php?entityName=$1 [QSA]
```